# WebView not loading completely in other than MainActivity

Tags: android, webview

I'm working on an app where I render pages of Facebook but I'm facing issues loading webview in other activities than MainActivity.. **Facebook page gets loaded completely only in MainActivity** but not in others.. Either in Dialogs it won't load. 
**It loads only the Facebook navbar... but not the page content...**
I have simplest code in activities and dialog to load webview:

```
WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
view.getSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
view.loadUrl("facebook page url");
```

**This code loads the page flawlessly in MainActivity** but it won't load neither in Dialogs or in other activities... It's like somehow it has cached.. and reproduces same problem in all over the app except MainActivity...
Any clue about why this happens and how I can get rid of this issue?

Comment: There is a good chance this is because of something in your code that you haven't thought to mention, not the WebView (or this code) specifically.

Comment: My bad... I had some conflicting code in shouldOvverrideUrl function of webclient... Nm issue solved.. Thanks for pointing :)